# Standard titles in web form

Tags: forms, web

What are the standard abbreviation you would use for salutations in a web form?

I can think of:

- Mr.
- Mrs.
- Dr.

This would go in an

```
<select name="prefix">
  <option selected="selected">Mr</option>
  <option>Mrs</option>
  <option>Dr</option>
</select>
```

and i do not want to make any typo / miss the obvious ones...

Comment: This page has a number of examples. http://www.formisimo.com/blog/thank-you-for-joining-speedycomposte-com-baroness-claudia/ showing how attempting to be inclusive quickly becomes ridiculous. Personally I recommend not including such a field. I think it's no longer necessary in the 21st century. Good form design says limit the number of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky one ... Wikipedia has a list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics  but it doesn't include military royal honorifics. There is an English noble titles list too (in case the queen registers) version http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtesy_titles_in_the_United_Kingdom